# Passing 'self' as an argument in a function call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, self

In my gui application (PyQt 5) I have a couple of code pieces appearing repeatedly in different modules. This is an example:

```py
save_file = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(
                                    self,
                                    "Save",
                                    directory="path/to/filename"
                                )
save_path = save_file[0]
```

I thought about writing a function for that like this:

```py
def save_file(obj, title, preset):
    save_file = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(obj, title, preset)
    save_path = save_file[0]
    return save_path
```

And whenever I need it (*in some class*) I would call it in this way:

```py
save_file(self, "Save testfile", os.path.join(file_path, file_name))
```

In this case I would have to pass `self` as an argument to my function. Is this ok? 
I know I can pass an instance of a class as an argument. 
But is it a good idea passing `self` directly when calling the function within a method? 
I couldn't find much about that on the internet.

Comment: Please work through a tutorial on calling class methods.

Answer (score 0):

That is fine, though the convention is to use the following format:

```
self.save_file("Save testfile", "path/to/filename")
```

Though the `save_file` should probably be within a class and its method definition look like:

```
def save_file(self, title, preset):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`self` is typically used to refer to `this` object. The one in whose method you are currently. You have not given enough context for a complete answer, but you should read up on python classes, and the use of class methods. Here's [a tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).